# How to check if unix process is running using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to check if the process is actively running from the unix system.It can be one process or multiple process .Following is the example that i am trying. Can someone guide me how this can be achieved ?

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test cases ***
Example
     ${output} =     Run process   /etc/init.d/bluetooth
     ${op}=     Is Process Running   ${output} 
     Should be equal     ${op}     True

[root@test ssh-scripts]# pybot test-process.robot 
==============================================================================
Test-Process                                                                  
==============================================================================
Example                                                               | FAIL |
Non-existing index or alias '<result object with rc 3>'.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test-Process                                                          | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `/etc/init.d/bluetooth` is startup script, you won't to check the startup script but rather the process(es) started by it
2. Keyword `Run Process` waits till the process terminates. You probably won't wait for termination, you rather want to run the process on background.

This works as expected for me:

```
Test Processes
    ${handle}    Start Process    echo    foo    stdout=/tmp/bar
    ${output}    Is Process Running    handle=${handle}
    Should Not Be True    ${output}
    ${handle}    Start Process    yes    stdout=/dev/null
    ${output}    Is Process Running    handle=${handle}
    Should Be True    ${output}
    [Teardown]    Terminate All Processes
```

I.e. `echo` terminates earlier than the first `Is Process Running` check is performed. But `yes` is started and keeps running in the moment of second `Is Process Running`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, i will try the answer , my purpose is to check the process like below  `[root@hy init.d]# MDB_Platform_PostgreSQL status
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 9997)`   . I want to verify whether this process is running or not  , like this i have a set of process to be verified .

Answer (score 0):

Following script worked for me . I have placed a regex pattern to match the string after command is executed. This can achieved in alternate way but this served my purpose.

```
*** Settings ***

Library                Process
Library                SSHLibrary
Suite Setup            Open Connection And Log In
Suite Teardown         Close All Connections
Library                OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***

${HOST}                16.10.90.24
${USERNAME}            root
${PASSWORD}            admin123
${postgres_cmd}         /etc/init.d/DB_Platform_TaskManager  status
${PATTERN}             (?m).*is\ running


*** Test Cases ***
Check whether postgres is running 
   Open Connection And Log In
   Start Command     ${postgres_cmd}
   ${rc}=    Read Command Output   return_stdout=True   return_rc=False
   Log    ${rc}
   Should Match Regexp    ${rc}     ${PATTERN}

*** Keywords ***
Open Connection And Log In
   Open Connection    ${HOST}
   Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
```